# What is the difference between int and (int) in C?

Tags: c, integer

For example: when I round a float into an int, why should I use :

`int i = (int) round(f);`

Instead of :

`int i = int round(f);`

Comment: If you are learning C from a book, throw that book away and get a better one. If you are learning it from some online resource, blacklist that site and never visit it again. This question is trivial once you get a basic understanding of the syntax of C language.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well by convention, doing (int) on a float is typecasting the float to an int. I'm not quite sure why you'd do int _ = int _ , although it may work just as well. By convention though, many languages (there are exceptions) in which you typecast go by the syntax of

```
... = (_type_) yourdatavalue
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is wrong. THere is no common syntax for type conversion/typecast. Ada for instance uses `type_conversion ::= type_mark(expression)`. C++ works partially with templates.

Comment: Python: `int(5.2) == 5`

Comment: @ace: That requires the type class object to be callable, but : yes (how could I forget about Python).

Comment: I should have said most.. oops.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between int and (int) in C?

an `int` is the built-in type integer and `(int)` is [Type Casting](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm).

Answer (score 1):

In C float data values require more storage, So when you are storing a float value in an integer variable you are supposed to type cat it to truncate the fractional part before storing it.

i.e. int i = (int) round(f);

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually try to compile the latter? I will not answer that until you report what the compiler says.

For the first version: That is a [typecast](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.4) (read about the semantics), telling the compiler to convert the value to the type in the parenthesis. Otherwise the compiler might (should) complain about assigning a more "powerful" type to a lesser.

Note that "powerful" here means the type can hold a larger range of values; not necessarily higher precision.

Edit: Yes, you will get "expected expression" for the latter. Because that is simply invalid. So, the simple and full answer is: because the second thing is not valid C and will not even compiler!

Comment: @user4241464: I updated my answer. Whoever told you so: kick her where it hurts and get a good C-book.:-)

Answer (score 0):

use `int i` is a definition.

`(int) round(f)` is **casting** the results of the round function to an integer, potentially truncating results of `round` down to an integer

Comment: The result of `round(f)` is an integer.  That `double` value, when cast via `(int)`, will not incur another truncation - just a type change.